# Add a new field to Sitecore JSS

Tags: sitecore, jss

I created a simple Sitecore JSS Application and imported the same.
In connected mode, I want to add a few new fields. I added them to the template (Image 1) and they show up in the item (Image 2). When I query the item, I get the new fields in the json object as well (Image 4).
However, I cannot see the new fields in the experience editor (Image 3) and I am assuming I need to add those in the View. I am unable to locate where I need to add these fields or what I need to do, to have these show up.

**Image 1: The modified template**
[image: The new fields are description and photo]

**Image 2: Both description and photo show up in the item**
[image: Both description and photo show up in the item]

**Image 3: Description and photo do not show up in the experience editor**
[image: Description and photo do not show up in the experience editor]

**Image 4: Json however returns these 2 properties**
[image: Json however returns these 2 properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Experience Editor use the Node.js app inside the `/dist` folder of your Sitecore webroot. (See also the config, you can have multiple apps)
Change your frontend, I Guess you use React, Vue, or Angular and upload/deploy to the dist folder.

You need to choose your dev workflow see:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/development-workflows.html
When you add your fields in Sitecore, you are using the Sitecore-First Workflow.

Hidden gem:
JSS add a extra Field "Always Display Field Editor Button in Experience Editor" to Renderings. In the Experience editor the Chrome Toolbar from a rendering has as first icon a Pencil, That opens a Field editor for all custom fields.